# Surround Sound 7.1 USB Headset set up

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headset

I've seen multiple versions of this problem on this site and others but none have really been much help.
I'm trying to set up my Turtle Beach Z60 headset so that it plays in surround sound and have run into a number of issues.

I've successfully edited `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` so that `default-sample-channels = 8`. The problem with this however is that when I try `speaker-test -c 8` the side left, rear left, side right and rear right volumes are much lower than the front left, front centre, front right and rear centre. Not only this but the sound quality of the speakers is very low compared to how they usually work on windows.

Finally, when I try to select the sound card in `alsamixer` I get the error
`cannot load mixer controls: Invalid argument`.

My `/proc/asound/card1/stream0` file is

> Turtle Beach Turtle Beach Z60 Game Audio at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, full speed : USB Audio
>
> Playback:
>
> > Status: Stop
> >
> > Interface 2
> >
> > > Altset 1
> > >
> > > Format: S16_LE
> > >
> > > Channels: 2
> > >
> > > Endpoint: 1 OUT (ADAPTIVE)
> > >
> > > Rates: 16000
> > >        Interface 2
> > >          Altset 2
> > >
> > > Format: S24_3LE
> > >
> > > Channels: 2
> > >
> > > Endpoint: 1 OUT (ADAPTIVE)
> > >
> > > Rates: 16000
>
> Capture:
>
> > Status: Stop
> >
> > Interface 1
> >
> > > Altset 1
> > >
> > > Format: S16_LE
> > >
> > > Channels: 2
> > >
> > > Endpoint: 1 IN (ADAPTIVE)
> > >
> > > Rates: 16000
> > >        Interface 1
> > >          Altset 2
> > >
> > > Format: S24_3LE
> > >
> > > Channels: 2
> > >
> > > Endpoint: 1 IN (ADAPTIVE)
> > >
> > > Rates: 16000

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please show the contents of `/proc/asound/cardX/stream0`.

Comment: Bump. I too am having this issue. I even have the exact same headset (Turtle Beach Z60 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). Sound plays through the headset however it is very low.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I hope posting might help some people out. It took me quite a while fiddling around with this headset to get proper sound. I am no expert on alsa or pulse-audio.

The following is done on Fedora Linux 33 but is likely relevant for Ubuntu users too.

This headset has a channel for voice chat (low quality) and a channel for normal audio. Plugging in this headset only makes the low quality sound available to pulse-audio. This can be verified by playing audio and turning the volume wheel on the controller on the USB-cord. Changing the volume only works using the voice channel wheel.

You can see the low sample size:

```
pactl list sinks
Sink #5
        State: SUSPENDED
        Name: alsa_output.usb-Turtle_Beach_Turtle_Beach_Z60_Game_Audio_000000000000-00.analog-stereo
        Description: Turtle Beach Z60 Game Audio Analog Stereo
        Driver: module-alsa-card.c
        Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 16000Hz
```

If I look at the different steams in /proc/asound/card0 (my headphones are card0, yours may vary) I can see stream0 is 16000Hz and stream1 is the proper sound quality steam:

```
[stephan@nyx ~]$ cat /proc/asound/card0/stream0
Turtle Beach Turtle Beach Z60 Game Audio at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, full speed : USB Audio

Playback:
  Status: Stop
  Interface 2
    Altset 1
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 1 OUT (ADAPTIVE)
    Rates: 16000
    Bits: 16
    Channel map: FL FR
  Interface 2
    Altset 2
    Format: S24_3LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 1 OUT (ADAPTIVE)
    Rates: 16000
    Bits: 24
    Channel map: FL FR

Capture:
  Status: Stop
  Interface 1
    Altset 1
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 1 IN (ADAPTIVE)
    Rates: 16000
    Bits: 16
    Channel map: FL FR
  Interface 1
    Altset 2
    Format: S24_3LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 1 IN (ADAPTIVE)
    Rates: 16000
    Bits: 24
    Channel map: FL FR
[stephan@nyx ~]$ cat /proc/asound/card0/stream1
Turtle Beach Turtle Beach Z60 Game Audio at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, full speed : USB Audio #1

Playback:
  Status: Running
    Interface = 4
    Altset = 1
    Packet Size = 192
    Momentary freq = 44100 Hz (0x2c.199a)
  Interface 4
    Altset 1
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 2 OUT (ADAPTIVE)
    Rates: 8000, 11025, 16000, 22050, 24000, 32000, 44100, 48000
    Bits: 16
    Channel map: FL FR
  Interface 4
    Altset 2
    Format: S24_3LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 2 OUT (ADAPTIVE)
    Rates: 8000, 11025, 16000, 22050, 24000, 32000, 44100, 48000
    Bits: 24
    Channel map: FL FR
  Interface 4
    Altset 3
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 8
    Endpoint: 2 OUT (ADAPTIVE)
    Rates: 8000, 11025, 16000, 22050, 24000, 32000, 44100, 48000
    Bits: 16
    Channel map: FL FR FC LFE SL SR FLC FRC
```

This is good news and probably means that there is no driver problem but something in the userland is not selecting the right output stream.

Using the aplay command I figured out my card has two devices. I assumed the stream1 is on the second device (device 1) which in ALSA is called hw:0,1

```
[stephan@nyx ~]$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Audio [Turtle Beach Z60 Game Audio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Audio [Turtle Beach Z60 Game Audio], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I verified the quality on this device by opening VLC with this specific output device. Start VLC and play an audio file

```
vlc --aout alsa --alsa-audio-device hw:0,1
```

After verifying that the sound quality is now what it is supposed to be I create a sink in Pulse-audio using the ALSA device

```
pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,1
```

In GNOME I can now see a new audio device called "Turtle Beach Z60 Game Audio". Using this as an output device the sound quality is great. You can verify that the right channel is used by turning the volume wheel on the USB-cord controller. It should react to the normal volume wheel instead of the voice wheel.

You can make the change to pulse-audio permanent by adding this line to /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,1
```

Listing the sinks in pulse-audio now shows the right sample size for the sink

```
Sink #6
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.hw_0_1
    Description: Turtle Beach Z60 Game Audio
    Driver: module-alsa-sink.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
```

Note that it shows only two channels, not surround. This is likely a setting that can be made somewhere but I'm not interested in surround sound. This at least fixes the sound quality by using the right channel.

Maybe there is a more elegant solution to this problem but this works for me.

Comment: Regarding `... which in ALSA is called hw:0,1`, how did you find its name in ALSA?